# "To whom"/"Whom to" is that boy running?

Tags: word-order, who-whom

Given the sentence

> That boy is running to his mother.

How can this be turned into an object-related question?

1. To whom is that boy running?
2. Whom to is that boy running?

Comment: Not many people still bother with ***whom*** anyway (it's usually just ***who*** everywhere today). But it's also worth noting that since everyone now openly sneers at the pedantic Victorian pedant's rule about not ending a sentence with a preposition, most of us now put ***to*** at the end here. So the "natural" version today is ***Who** is he running **to**?* That's a *slightly* uncommon question anyway, but it's easy to establish the basic preference here by comparing ***Where are you going to**?* (standard) with ***To where are you going**?* (uncommon / dated / poetic).

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure I even understand the question. I am guessing it is

> How would we turn the sentence “The boy was running to his mother” into a question if the boy’s goal was unknown?

If that is the gist of the question, then

> To whom was the boy running

is fine, but

> Whom to the boy was running

is totally wrong.

When the interrogative pronoun is the object of a preposition, the inversion into a question does not affect the normal order of the prepositional phrase.

Comment: 'To whom was the boy running' is fine in conversation if you want to be considered weird.

Answer (score 1):

"To whom" because the fronted pronoun "whom" is preceded by the preposition.

The same pattern can been seen in other question forms:

> The cat is sitting on the mat.

> On what is the cat sitting?

In a sentence with a subject, direct object and indirect object, three questions can be formed:

> John gave the ball to Peter.

> To whom did John give the ball?

> What did John give to Peter?

> Who gave the ball to Peter?

But in standard, non-formal English, the question is constructed differently:

> Who is that boy running to?

Comment: So, apart from in old-fashioned tests looking at archaic English, "To whom is that boy running?" sounds pompous / ridiculous (?)

Comment: Ask not for whom the bell tolls, Ask "Who is that bell tolling for?"

Comment: Old-fashioned tests looking at archaic English. And archaic English.

Comment: And some people sound as though they do not know English.